# Unexpected error in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller

I am learning angularjs & facing error with angularjs
I am trying to create a simple angular module getting error
but sample controller function working ok without mudule 
I write the same code of video where from I am learning

Here is code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="demoApp">
<head>
    <title>
        Angular js
    </title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="containers" ng-controller="simpleController">
<input type="text" ng-model="name">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter: name" | orderBy:'city'>{{ cust.name | uppercase}} - {{ cust.city | lowercase}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp'. []);
    function simpleController ($scope) {
        $scope.customers = [
        {name:'Dinesh', city:'Delhi'},
        {name:'Hansa', city:'Rajasthan'},
        {name:'Manju', city:'Rajasthan'},
        {name:'Mukesh', city:'Rajasthan'},
        {name:'Naresh', city:'Lahor'}
        ];
    }
    demoApp.controller('simpleController', simpleController);
</script>
</body>
</body>
</html>
```

but my app not work properly, display error like below
[image]

Now my this question is solve 
this code is working with  AngularJS v1.2.28 but same code not work with AngularJS v1.5.5
Thanks for help in advance

Comment: with the answer app is working, it work with  AngularJS v1.2.28 but not work with latest AngularJS v1.5.5,I attached error with question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is ok 
except `angular.module('demoApp'. [])`,
 must be `angular.module('demoApp', [])`  - comma instead of dot, and be more attentive

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp'. []); //REPLACE DOT WITH COMMA
    function simpleController ($scope) {
        $scope.customers = [
        {name:'Dinesh', city:'Delhi'},
        {name:'Hansa', city:'Rajasthan'},
        {name:'Manju', city:'Rajasthan'},
        {name:'Mukesh', city:'Rajasthan'},
        {name:'Naresh', city:'Lahor'}
        ];
    }
    demoApp.controller('simpleController', simpleController);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

`var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp'. []);`

It should be

`var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', []);`

A comma instead of a period. Just a syntax error :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the previous answers, I don't see you referencing the ng-app directive in your HTML so that should be in your body tag like this:
body ng-app="demoApp"

Comment: he has used the `ng-app` directive on the HTML tag.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
angular.module('demoApp'. []),
must be angular.module('demoApp', []) - comma instead of dot
```